# How to get user from Kentico

Tags: c#, asp.net, kentico

I want to get all user member in Kentico for show on my user control[Gridview]. but when  test in kentico. my gridview was show "SELECT * FROM CMS_User" I don't know about it

This is my code

```
        var users = UserInfoProvider.GetUsers();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[2] { new DataColumn("FullName"), new  DataColumn("Username") });

      foreach (UserInfo aUser in users)
        {

            dt.Rows.Add(users);

         }

        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at the kentico article for specifically using Kentico's tools for displaying data  https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Displaying+data+from+custom+tables

However, assuming you are creating your own webpart, you should change your code to explicitly map the properties to a new row for your table....

```
var users = UserInfoProvider.GetUsers();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[2] { new DataColumn("FullName"), new DataColumn("UserName") });

            foreach (UserInfo aUser in users.TypedResult)
            {
                DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();
                newRow["FullName"] = aUser.FullName;
                newRow["UserName"] = aUser.UserName;
                dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
            }

            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thank  you very much sir
You are my light :)